# is it possible not to change an UIImageView frame when rotating an UIImage?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, frame, bounds

I got a quick question;

I've got an UIImage inside an UIImageView that I rotate (only the image).
As you know the frame will scale up so everything fits. Is it possible to ignore this behavior?

I just want to keep the frames where they, it doesn't matter if the corners are outside the frame.

Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried using math to find the image inside then crop and rotate it back, but it's a hassle.  Forgot to say that I'm using the image as a mask, but that works.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use a `UIImageView`?  Maybe you can drop down to the `CALayer` level and apply transforms there without the internal bounds-changing hooks present in `UIView`.